# Delphi - Checklist for PAServer Connection (Mac OSX)

Tags: macos, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo, paserver

I have spent the better part of a day trying to connect to PAServer on MAC OSX from my Windows PC with no luck. I am not sure what I am missing.

I am using Delphi 10.2 Tokyo on Windows. Trying to connect to PAServer 19.0 on a Mac Mini running macOS Sierra (10.12.4) on which I already have XCode (v8.3.2) installed along with Command Line Tools.

Both the dev machine as well as the Mac Mini are connected to the same Wifi network. I even tried connecting both machines to a different network but with the same issue.

I get the same error message every time that the connection failed. I suspect that it has something to do with the network - where the 2 machines cannot see each other, but I don't know how I can confirm this or resolve it. I have tried to search on SO as well as online but have not found anything that has helped.

Has anyone seen this issue and overcome it? Is there a set of steps I can go thru to troubleshoot this? Any help or guidance would be most appreciated!

Comment: Maybe a dumb question but is your PAServer running on the mac when you try it ? There should be a console like window when it is running. And can both machines ping each other ?

Comment: PAServer is running on the Mac. But the machines cannot ping each other (which is why I think it might be network related?)...

Comment: if both machines are on the same network (have same first 3 parts of the ip-address) then it should work. Maybe a firewall issue ? You could also try disabling ip6 on both machines

Comment: @GuidoG They are on the same network and the first 3 parts of IP address are the same. Even I thought it might be a firewall issue so I disabled the firewall on both machines - but that did not help. :(

Comment: Even if you were able to connect, creating an ad-hoc or app store app won't work (yet) with Xcode 8.3.2, so you may want to consider reverting to 8.2.1

Comment: Why is that @davenottage? I bought the mac mini just a couple days ago - just for multi platform development and it came pre-installed with Sierra and when I got Xcode from the store I guess it installed the latest version.

Comment: @Rohit Because PAServer sometimes needs updating when a new version of Xcode comes out. For whatever reason, apparently PAServer that comes with Tokyo is not totally compatible with Xcode 8.3.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I kept trying out different things and was able to solve this issue (one way to solve it I guess).

Because it seemed like it was network related, I tried first to create a hotspot with my phone and connected the dev machine and the Mac Mini to it. The PAServer connection worked.

So I looked for a way to do this via Windows. Here are the steps I followed:

1. Open `Settings > Network & Internet` (on Windows 10)
2. Go into `Mobile Hotspot` and select `Wi-Fi` in the `Share my
   Connection From` dropdown
3. Set a `Network name` and `Network password`
4. Turn on `Share my Internet connection with other devices`

Now on the Mac, connect to the network name we set up in step 3 and enter the password that was set. Then start PAServer on the Mac. That's it!

Now when you connect from Delphi to PAServer, the connection succeeds.

**Note:** Interestingly, when I was not using the mobile hotspot method on Windows, the IP address on PAServer (and on Windows) was 10.xx.xx.xx. With the mobile hotspot, the IP address is 192.xx.xx.xx.

Answer (score 0):

I just configured (today) a new macos sierra with paserver. yes it's painfull :(
don't use virtualbox (it's buggy and slow), but use instead VMware, it's work like a charm. it's much more easy to have only one computer to develop than 2. also you can copy/past the log or anythink else from macosx to windows (or vice-versa) in just one click. and you will not have any internet problem or anything else ...